# ggplot2 inside function with a 2nd aesthetic: scoping issue

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following test data:

```
structure(list(r = c(5.44702625911984, 6.3431860464319, 2.89023592667928, 
6.66260769449341, 7.5521021076857, 5.50645078944005, 6.70001850525037, 
7.39615449137166, 5.96032231142622, 7.88929821115731, 9.45119299499902, 
6.13534105776075, 7.79397401855071, 5.24488870603935, 4.53178061905952, 
5.80573244536445, 10.1194252475799, 12.5794215385996, 7.47503723957468, 
7.8682648760597, 15.7540766770233, 14.9800818974568, 14.5672865569748, 
9.5347507057429, 18.6791666362954, 10.4588651710497, 15.2076130678251, 
10.5052588219606, 13.1314628288852, 12.8384811800557, 10.9978569438483, 
10.0197995395016, 10.1479274794689, 12.5864754383382, 10.7985399338233, 
11.1100572430765, 10.756576992292, 9.17309427876051, 10.0441987112265, 
10.0652520950654), f1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("H", "L"), class = "factor"), f2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), class = "factor", .Label = c("Joe", 
"Sally"))), .Names = c("r", "f1", "f2"), row.names = c(NA, -40L
), class = "data.frame")
```

And the following function which should draw the points (it does) and connect the means of each group (it doesn't):

```
testFunc <- function(formula = NULL, data = NULL) {
    res <- as.character(formula[[2]])
    fac1 <- as.character(formula[[3]][2])
    fac2 <- as.character(formula[[3]][3])

    # Specify the data & aesthetics     
    p <- ggplot(data, aes_string(x = fac1, y = res, color = fac2,
        group = fac2))

    # Now add points
    p <- p + geom_point() # works fine if we stop here

    # Due to a bug in ggplot2_0.9.3, we must calc some quantities
    # and put them in a separate data frame for a new aesthetic
    avg <- aggregate(data[,res] ~ data[,fac1]*data[, fac2], data, FUN = mean)
    names(avg) <- c("factor1", "factor2", "mean")   
    p <- p + geom_line(aes_string(x = 'factor1', y = 'mean', group = 'factor2'), data = avg)
    }
```

When I run it:

```
ex <- testFunc(formula = r ~ f1*f2, data = td)
print(ex)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'f2' not found
```

I seem to always have these scoping problems, any advice?  I thought I was following the appropriate work-around for the bug.  Using `aes` instead of `aes_string`, or not quoting the variable names in `geom_line` doesn't fix it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run into trouble with inherited aesthetics, I always go back and remove anything from the main `ggplot()` call that doesn't need to be there. Try this:

```
testFunc <- function(formula = NULL, data = NULL) {
    res <- as.character(formula[[2]])
    fac1 <- as.character(formula[[3]][2])
    fac2 <- as.character(formula[[3]][3])

    # Now add points
    p <- ggplot() + geom_point(data = data, aes_string(x = fac1, y = res, color = fac2,
        group = fac2)) # works fine if we stop here

    # Due to a bug in ggplot2_0.9.3, we must calc some quantities
    # and put them in a separate data frame for a new aesthetic
    avg <- aggregate(data[,res] ~ data[,fac1]*data[, fac2], data, FUN = mean)
    names(avg) <- c("factor1", "factor2", "mean")   
    p <- p + geom_line(aes_string(x = 'factor1', y = 'mean', group = 'factor2'), data = avg)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Joran.  Works of course.  But why?  I'd guess just calling `ggplot()` alone/empty allows one to separate the `geom_point` aesthetic from the `geom_line` aesthetic cleanly, and doesn't pollute the initial `proto` object - is that the way to think about it?  Thanks so much for the insight.

Comment: Basically, yes. Anything included in `ggplot()` will be passed on down to each layer, unless specifically overridden. My guess is that in this case something's going wrong with `aes_string`'s attempt to stomp out the originally set aesthetics of x,y and group in `ggplot`. It could possibly be a bug, but it could also be just an limitation of `aes_string` that's unavoidable.

Comment: Your analysis is right, but the problem is the color aesthetic which is set in the original ggplot call but then is not overridden in the `geom_line` aesthetics that use the `avg` data (which doesn't have an `f2` variable). So you can leave `data, aes_string(x = fac1, y = res, group = fac2)` in the original `ggplot` call and just put `aes_string(color = fac2)` in the `geom_point` call and that will suffice.

Comment: Thanks Brian, understood.  The test function works well now, but the real function has many options and potential layers (some discrete, some continuous).  I'm getting a `Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` error on the real function.  So that's the next task.  Unfortunately, it might be tough to make a MWE out of it.

Comment: Thanks @BrianDiggs, I totally missed the color/group aesthetic difference between the two layers. Need to have my eyes checked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make two changes to get your function to work. First, there's a bug in ggplot2 0.9.3 (and previous) where the evaluation environment of `aes()` defaults to the global environment. The workaround: to make it evaluate in the calling environment (for example, your function's environment) use `ggplot(..., environment = environment()`.

The other change was in the last line, where you have `p <- p + geom_line(..., data=avg)`. The key there is that you must turn off the inheritance of aesthetics from the main `ggplot` call, because your `avg` data set doesn't have the `fac2` column. To do that, use `geom_line(..., inherit.aes=FALSE)`.

```
testFunc <- function(formula = NULL, data = NULL) {
  res <- as.character(formula[[2]])
  fac1 <- as.character(formula[[3]][2])
  fac2 <- as.character(formula[[3]][3])

  # Specify the data & aesthetics     
  p <- ggplot(data, aes_string(x = fac1, y = res, color = fac2, group = fac2),
    environment = environment())

  # Now add points
  p <- p + geom_point()

  # Due to a bug in ggplot2_0.9.3, we must calc some quantities
  # and put them in a separate data frame for a new aesthetic
  avg <- aggregate(data[,res] ~ data[,fac1]*data[, fac2], data, FUN = mean)
  names(avg) <- c("factor1", "factor2", "mean")   
  p + geom_line(aes_string(x = 'factor1', y = 'mean', group = 'factor2'), 
    inherit.aes = FALSE, data = avg)
}

ex <- testFunc(formula = r ~ f1*f2, data = td)
print(ex)
```