# ggplot2 + aes_string inside a function via formula interface

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Interactively, this example works fine:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(. ~ vs)
```

Now, make a function with a formula interface and use `aes_string` to do this same thing, and it doesn't work (error is: `Error in layout_base(data, cols, drop = drop) : At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting`):

```
tf <- function(formula, data) {
res <- as.character(formula[[2]])
fac2 <- as.character(formula[[3]][3])
fac1 <- as.character(formula[[3]][2])

# p <- ggplot(aes_string(x = fac1, y = res), data = data)
# p <- p + geom_point() # original attempt
p <- ggplot() # This is Joran's trick, but it doesn't work here
p <- p + geom_point(aes_string(x = fac1, y = res), data = data)
p <- p + facet_grid(.~fac2) # comment this out, and it works but
# of course is not faceted
}

p <- tf(formula = wt ~ am*vs, data = mtcars)
```

By Joran's trick I refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348781/ggplot2-inside-function-with-a-2nd-aesthetic-scoping-issue), which is a similar question I posted recently.  In this case `ggplot2`doesn't see my faceting request. Making it `facet_grid(".~fac2")` had no effect.  Suggestions?  I'm continually out-witted by these things.  Thanks!

Comment: What is an example value of `fac2`? (Is it just a vector, or a more complicated formula?)

Comment: `fac2` would be like `fac1`, a character string giving the name of a data frame column which is a factor or coerces to one.  It is reproducible, look at the last line using `mtcars`.

Comment: I think it will be far easier to have the facetting formula as a second argument, otherwise you will have to build a new parser for however you are wishing to differentiate between faceting and coordinate variables

Comment: @mnel, not completely sure what you mean - move the faceting to where?

Comment: See my answer. Hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `as.formula` and `paste`:

```
p <- p + facet_grid(as.formula(paste(". ~", fac2)))
```

In your example, this gives:

[image]

Comment: Dang, the combination I never got around to!  Thank you.

Comment: and you don't even need to convert to formula, the `p <- p + facet_grid(paste(". ~", fac2))` will work just fine!

Answer (score 6):

I have used `formula.tools` for manipulating formulae.

I think you should have a separate argument for the faceting formula, otherwise you will have to create your own parser to work out what `wt ~ am*vs` means in terms of faceting

something like the lattice grouping idea might be useful

`wt~am | vs`

but you would have to delve into lattice to see how they parse their formulas (look at`latticeParseFormula` - complicated!)

Easier just to separate the two formulae. You can pass a list of character variables as rhs and lhs for the `facet` argument to `facet_grid`

I've also used `environment = parent.frame()` which works in my small testing

```
library(formula.tools)

tf <- function(formula, faceting = NULL, data, print = TRUE) {
   y <- rhs(formula)
   x <- lhs(formula)

  p <- ggplot(environment = parent.frame()) 

  p <- p + geom_point(aes_string(x = x, y = y), data = data) 
   if (! is.null(faceting)){
     rhsfacet <- all.vars(rhs(faceting))
     lhsfacet <- all.vars(lhs(faceting))
     if(length(lhsfacet)==1 & any(lhsfacet %in% '.')) {lhsfacet <- NULL}
     if(length(rhsfacet)==1 & any(rhsfacet %in% '.')) {rhsfacet <- NULL}
     p <- p+ facet_grid(facet = list( lhsfacet, rhsfacet))}
  if(print) {print(p)}
  p 

}
tf(wt~mpg, faceting = ~am, data = mtcars, print = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: I see what you mean now.  You are using a couple of interesting tools I need to look into.  I'm also interested the idea of passing a list to `facet` which I hadn't seen before.  Just checked, it's not documented in the current 0.9.3 pages.

Comment: Yes. I got there from looking at the source. I presumed there would be a way given how `.` and `as.quoted` works in `plyr`. I've also edited to be more robust to complex faceting formula (and no faceting)